# Can't use org-capture: `Capture template ‘t’: listp`

Tags: debugging, emacs, org-mode

Running the example of the org manual, https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html

I evaluate the following code in emacs:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
             "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
        ("j" "Journal" entry (file+olp+datetree "~/org/journal.org")
             "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

Then I run `M-x org-capture t`. The following error is printed and I can't capture anything: `org-capture: Capture template ‘t’: listp`

Here is the full backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture template ‘t’: listp")
  signal(error ("Capture template ‘t’: listp"))
  error("Capture template `%s': %s" "t" listp)
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was caused by `org-blank-before-new-entry` set to `t`